# Turning Histogram values into Numerical format ( Excel-xslx, Pandas-DataFrame, etc.)

Tags: categorical-data, web-scraping

I am trying to do a correlation study about personality traits as described in Hofstede's :https://www.hofstede-insights.com/product/compare-countries/  . I would like to have the values described in the bar charts numerically into, say an Excel or pandas file. Is there a way of scraping or using an API that would turn the bar chart values into number values associated to each country? I looked at similar questions but the closest I found was transforming categorical data given in a file format and did not involve scraping/APIs to change categorical into numerical.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data is available in json format through [this link](https://www.hofstede-insights.com/wp-json/v1/country), which contains the data for all countries that can be selected from the list. I found this link by going to the link you provided,  opening the Network tab in the Chrome developer tools and reloading the page to see  all the resources that are loaded by the webpage.

Comment: Excelent man, worked perfectly with Pandas.